# heat.exe - disable self registration

Tags: wix, windows-installer, regsvr32

Can I disable self registration dlls from heat? I use heat to generate list of files which should be added to msi, I don't want to register them during generation. One of files (*.dll) is self encrypted and I'm not able to register it (I don't even want it) but heat tries to do it. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the -scom and -sreg arguments when you execute heat this will stop it from generating the COM registration information in the output. The documentation for heat with the explanatory information for all parameters can be found [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html)

Comment: The documentation site appears to be down currently.